How to access an element of global style from C# code?
I want to use a global style for a textbox and change the color of the textbox if the textbox empty when I have clicked to a button. I have written these so far:
App.xaml

<Application x:Class="MVPInterface.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVPInterface"
             StartupUri="TheTestWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="NameTextField" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <TextBox BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" Background="White">
                                <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="NameFieldColor" Color="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                                </TextBox.BorderBrush>
                            </TextBox>
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="gotFocusTimeline">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#ff007fc7"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="lostFocusTimeline">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource gotFocusTimeline}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>

                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource lostFocusTimeline}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

TheTestWindow.xaml

<Window x:Class="MVPInterface.TheTestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVPInterface"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="The Screen" Height="1080" Width="1920" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="{x:Null}" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Border Name="theWindow" CornerRadius="10" Background="Azure" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="3" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Focusable="True">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Name="myTextbox" Text="Tester" MinWidth="100" Width="320" Background="White" GotFocus="OnGotFocusBox" LostFocus="OnLostFocusBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource NameTextField}"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="mySubmitButton" Width="100" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,120,0,0" Click="TestClick" Style="{StaticResource GrayDefaultButtonStyle}">
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>


TheTestWindow.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace MVPInterface
{   
    public partial class TheTestWindow : Window
    {
    
        Color fieldGray = Color.FromArgb(255, 195, 195, 195);
        Color fieldBlue = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 127, 199);
        Color fieldPurple = Color.FromArgb(255, 126, 42, 144);

        public TheTestWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void TestClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (myTextbox.Text == null || myTextbox.Text.Text == "" || myTextbox.Text.Text[0].Equals(" "))
            {

                ColorAnimation colorAnimationError = new ColorAnimation(fieldPurple, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
                NameFieldColor.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colorAnimationError);

           }

        private void MouseDrag(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                DragMove();

            }

            catch(Exception) 
            {

                MessageBox.Show("An exception ocurred...");
    
            }

        }

        private void WindowClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            theWindow.Focus();

        }


But, I see an error telling me NameFieldColor inside TheTestWindow.xaml.cs does not exists. I wonder how can I access the NameFieldColor I have defined in App.xaml from my backcode TheTestWindow.xaml.cs.

BONUS:

I got another thing I am curious about: After setting the style of the button to the global style, why I can't use content to show a text on the button? If I wanted the use this style on multiple buttons each of which should have a different text inside, how could I achieve that?

NOTES:

The reason for using a textbox inside the ControlTemplate of a TextBox was, as can be seen from the code, to make it possible to change the color of the Border of the TextBox when I hover or click on TextBox. When I have used the Border directly previously, the Border would change it's color only when the crsor is directly on the Border. Thus, most of the time when my cursor was actually on TextBox it wouldn't change color.

UPDATE:

After kind suggestions from @Clemens I have updated App.xaml and TheTestWindow.xaml.cs as such:
App.xaml

<Application x:Class="MVPInterface.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVPInterface"
             StartupUri="TheTestWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="NameTextField" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border x:Name="fieldBorder" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFC3C3C3" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>                                
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="gotFocusTimeline">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#ff007fc7"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="lostFocusTimeline">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource gotFocusTimeline}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>

                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource lostFocusTimeline}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

TheWindow.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace MVPInterface
{   
    public partial class TheTestWindow : Window
    {
    
        Color fieldGray = Color.FromArgb(255, 195, 195, 195);
        Color fieldBlue = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 127, 199);
        Color fieldPurple = Color.FromArgb(255, 126, 42, 144);

        public TheTestWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Style NameTextField = (Style)Resources["NameTextField"];
            ControlTemplate ntftemplate = (ControlTemplate)NameTextField.Setters.OfType<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Property == Control.TemplateProperty)?.Value;
            Border fieldBorder = (Border)ntftemplate.FindName("fieldBorder", NameTextField);
            
        }

        private void TestClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (myTextbox.Text == null || myTextbox.Text.Text == "" || myTextbox.Text.Text[0].Equals(" "))
            {

                ColorAnimation colorAnimationError = new ColorAnimation(fieldPurple, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
                NameFieldColor.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colorAnimationError);

           }

        private void MouseDrag(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                DragMove();

            }

            catch(Exception) 
            {

                MessageBox.Show("An exception ocurred...");
    
            }

        }

        private void WindowClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            theWindow.Focus();

        }


But, this time it gives me an error on it can't convert  System.Windows.Style to System.Window.FrameWorkElement on NameTextField at the line: Border fieldBorder = (Border)ntftemplate.FindName("fieldBorder", NameTextField);

You may want to take a look at TextBox Styles and Templates to find out how the (complex) TextBox Style looks like. A TextBox in the Template of TextBox makes no sense. There should be <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/> in a Border. Then you may also be interested in How to: Implement Binding Validation. Trying to manually animate the BorderBrush is certainly the wrong approach.

The names within the styles or templates don't exist outside. This is a different namescope. Creating a style for your buttons normally does not prevent you from setting the content propety locally. Based on how you have wrongfully templated the TeextBox I assume the template for the Button is also wrong.

I recommend to implement the animation in XAML, in the correct scope (--> in the Style). See my answer for a solution. You can also use DataTrigger together with a converter if your conditions are too complex to be realized with XAML alone.

You don't have to override the default template for this (the ControlTemplate itself is wrong as you may already know by now as you have already been told by other users).
Simply animate the TextBox.BorderBrush property from the style.
The following example shows how to animate the TextBox.BrderBrush when the TextBox is focused and the TextBox.Text property is null or empty.
App.xaml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="FocusedEmptyTextBoxBorderColor">Purple</Color>

    <Style x:Key="NameTextField" 
           TargetType="TextBox">

      <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                       Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text.IsEmpty}"
                       Value="True" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

          <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EmptyFocusedTexBoxAnimation">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                To="{StaticResource FocusedEmptyTextBoxBorderColor}" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EmptyFocusedTexBoxAnimation" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>

You can introduce binding converter(s) if the conditions are too complex in order to implement them in XAML.

In your original code, NameFieldColor is the BorderBrush of the inner TextBox in your template. If you want to animate this one, you need to get a reference to the inner TextBox. This should work:
private void TestClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox innerTextBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myTextbox, 0) as TextBox;
    if (innerTextBox != null)
    {
        if (myTextbox.Text == null || innerTextBox.Text == "" || innerTextBox.Text[0].Equals(" "))
        {
            ColorAnimation colorAnimationError = new ColorAnimation(fieldPurple, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
            innerTextBox.BorderBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, colorAnimationError);

        }
    }
}

Using the following Style in App.xaml (copied from your original question):
<Style x:Key="NameTextField" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <TextBox BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" Background="White">
                    <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="NameFieldColor" Color="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                    </TextBox.BorderBrush>
                </TextBox>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="gotFocusTimeline">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#ff007fc7"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="lostFocusTimeline">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="NameFieldColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.30" Value="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource gotFocusTimeline}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource lostFocusTimeline}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

The template of a TextBox should not contain another TextBox though but that's a different story.
